# socket client using background thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, tcpclient

I'm trying to write a C# client that's receiving a string from the server. I create a background thread that should wait for a response from the server at all times. When I start the program, I press a button (button1_Click_1) to start the thread that sends and receives messages, but I only receive some messages (maybe like 1 out of every 10). What am I doing wrong?

```
System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient clientSocket = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient();
Thread threadReceiveData;

string serverIP = some ip;    

static int port = 8200;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        msg("Client Started");
        clientSocket.Connect(serverIP, port);
        msg("Client Socket Program - Server Connected ...");
    }

    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        threadReceiveData = new Thread(new ThreadStart(startReceivingTrades));
        threadReceiveData.IsBackground = true;
        threadReceiveData.Start();     
    }

    private void startReceivingTrades()
    {
        while (true)
        {

            try
            {
                NetworkStream serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
                byte[] outStream = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("SendMeStuff" + System.Environment.NewLine);
                serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
                serverStream.Flush();

                byte[] inStream = new byte[10025];
                serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
                string returndata = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream);
                msg("Data from Server : " + returndata);
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                msg(ex.ToString());
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean to send "SendMeStuff" continously?  It seems more like that should only be sent **once**, outside the loop.

Also, use the **return value** from Read() in your GetString() call...and pass the length of your actual buffer being used:

```
private void startReceivingTrades()
{
    NetworkStream serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
    byte[] outStream = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("SendMeStuff" + System.Environment.NewLine);
    serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
    serverStream.Flush();

    byte[] inStream = new byte[10025];
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            int count = serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, inStream.Length);
            string returndata = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream, 0, count);
            msg("Data from Server : " + returndata);
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            msg(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just curious, whats the difference between the two methods? Between storing the return value from serverStream.Read() and not storing it? Why does it work when we store it and not when we don't?

Comment: Because your buffer `inStream` may not be "full" with valid data.  You can't control how much (or when) data gets received so you should only be using the part of the buffer that is known to contain valid data...and the return value tells you exactly how many bytes were received and placed into the buffer.  This information allows you, or GetString() in this case, to correctly convert only the portion of the buffer that has valid data in it.  The rest of the array just has junk in it.

Comment: Actaully I'm still not receiving all the messages!

Comment: What does `msg("Data from Server : " + returndata);` do?  You're going to have to give us more details if you want better help.  How do you know you're not receiving all messages?  What are you actually receiving?...what are you expecting?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - there was an error on the server side which the other programmer is looking into. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing your protocol, this has assumptions, but I think you meant something like this (i.e. you only need to get stream once, and send your sendmestuff message once only as well:

```
private void startReceivingTrades()
{
    NetworkStream serverStream;
        try
        {
            serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
            byte[] outStream = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("SendMeStuff" + System.Environment.NewLine);
            serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
            serverStream.Flush();
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            msg(ex.ToString());
        }

    while (true)
    {

        try
        {
            byte[] inStream = new byte[clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize];
            int bytesRead = serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, (int)inStream.Length);
            string returndata = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream, 0, bytesRead);
            msg("Data from Server : " + returndata);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            msg(ex.ToString());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Oops, see correction (don't have access to compiler atm.

Comment: Thanks for your response - that still doesn't work though. I put a breakpoint on the serverstream.read() line, which the program reaches, blocks the thread, and then doesn't do anything when I send it 4 messages

Comment: `Read` should unblock when some data is available... so that's a bit weird that it doesn't...  Not sure what's going on here...

Answer (score 1):

When a TCP question comes in I immediately go to the first `Read` call because invariably I find its return value unused. Use its return value to find out how many bytes were actually received.